# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 for Pig Latin

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program where the program translates on text file into pig latin. When I run it it says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1. Could you help me fix it. I will show you that part of the code that is incorrect.

```java
public static void piglatenizeFile(String fileNameIn, String fileNameOut) 
   {
      Scanner infile = null;
      String g = "";
      String output = "";
      String eachLetter = "";
      int index= -1;
      String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
      try
      {
         infile = new Scanner(new File(fileNameIn));  
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
         System.out.println("oops");
         System.exit(0);   
      }
   
      PrintWriter outfile = null;
      try
      {
         outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileNameOut));
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
         System.out.println("File not created");
         System.exit(0);
      }
      while(infile.hasNext()){// while txt has next line
         String sentence = infile.nextLine();// looks at next line
         String[] word = sentence.split(" ");//splits sentence to array of words
         for(int i=0;i<word.length;i++){//goes through every word in the sentence
            g =word[i].replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}]+", "");// replaces all punctuation
            for(int t=0;t<g.length();t++){// goes through every letter in each word
               eachLetter = g.substring(t,t+1);// eachLetter= each letter in noPunct
               if(eachLetter == vowels){
                  index = t;
                  t = g.length();
               }
            }
            output = g.substring(index)+ g.substring(0,index)+"ay";//ERROR
            outfile.print(output+" ");
         }
         outfile.print("\n");
      }

      outfile.close();
      infile.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Do not compare strings using `==`. Use `equals()`. Though in your case your should be using `contains()` like so: `if (vowels.contains(eachLetter))`

Comment: I suggest using Scanner and Tokenizer to work on "words" and not using for loops.

Answer (score 0):

In java when you use == on strings that's look on the stringpool(https://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool) so               `if(eachLetter == vowels){` it's always false so index will always stay at -1, as JustAnotherDeveloper say use equals and your if condition will be true sometime

Comment: In this case it won't be true if `equals()` is used, because the provided code will be comparing a single-character string with the string "aeiouAEIOU". As my comment states, the solution is using `contains()`.